# How can I stay connected to xbox live without other users (including friends) knowing that I'm online?

Tags: xbox-360

I know I can control whether others can *ever* see me, but I'm looking for the ability to *sometimes* mask my online status.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Push the Guide button
2. Go all the way right in the blades
3. Go to the "Online Status" menu item
4. Set yourself as "Appear Offline"

Answer (score -1):

Push the Guide button
Go all the way right in the blades
Go to the "ACTIVE STATUS" menu item
Set yourself as "Currently Offline"